# Issue while using a timer function in a threading context

Tags: python, multithreading

While working on a game for my final project in a class I’m taking I was trying to figure out how to use a timer but still be able to interact with other running code, in my research I came across threading and it’s worked so far, but the issue is that when it comes to practice, the timer doesn’t work but it rather rapidly repeats itself and I don’t know how to slow it down like I want. I’ve tried swapping the interval number for anything else but it doesn’t matter what it is, it remains to do the same thing.

-also I understand the code is messy, I’m a student and I’m still learning. I’m sure there are much better ways to do a lot of the things I have done. Also this is my first question on Stack overflow so I hope I’m doing this right

Its on lines 129 & 130

```
timer = threading.Timer(1, clickers)
timer.start
```

---

```
import turtle as trtl
import threading
import time
wn = trtl.Screen()

wn.bgpic("clouds.png")
font_setup = ("Arial", 15, "normal")
font_setup2 = ("Arial", 20, "bold")
sun_img = "sun.gif"
wn.addshape("sun.gif")
sun = trtl.Turtle(shape = sun_img)
sun.penup()
sun.goto(0, 175)
clkr_img = "rocketship.gif"
wn.addshape("rocketship.gif")
clkr = trtl.Turtle(shape = clkr_img)
clkr.penup()
clkr.left(90)
clkr.goto(0,-110)
moneya = trtl.Turtle()
moneya.hideturtle()
moneya.penup()
moneya.goto(-180, -180)
money = 0
upg1price = trtl.Turtle()
upg1price.hideturtle()
upg1price.penup()
upg1price.goto(63,-20)
csup = trtl.Turtle()
csup.hideturtle()
csup.penup()
csup.goto(63,-50)
broke = trtl.Turtle()
broke.hideturtle()
shoptf = 0
broke.penup()
broke.goto(-170,-30)
broke.pencolor("red")
shop_img = "cart.gif"
wn.addshape("cart.gif")
shop = trtl.Turtle(shape = shop_img)
shop.shapesize(0.5)
shop.penup()
shop.goto(150,150)
back_img = "backk.gif"
wn.addshape("backk.gif")
back = trtl.Turtle(shape = back_img)
back.penup()
back.hideturtle()
back.goto(-110,135)
ugrd_img = "upgrade1.gif"
wn.addshape("upgrade1.gif")
ugrd = trtl.Turtle(shape = ugrd_img)
ugrd.penup()
ugrd.goto(0,-10)
ugrd.hideturtle()
cs_img = "clicksla.gif"
wn.addshape("clicksla.gif")
cs = trtl.Turtle(shape = cs_img)
cs.penup()
cs.goto(0, -40)
cs.hideturtle()
dmg = 5
wn.addshape("rktboom.gif")
clkrdmg = 0
price = 50
price2= 75
fmvmnt = 1
def gostore(x,y):
  global price
  upg1price.write("$" + str(round(price)), font=font_setup)
  csup.write("$" + str(round(price2)), font=font_setup)
  back.showturtle()
  clkr.hideturtle()
  shop.hideturtle()
  ugrd.showturtle()
  cs.showturtle()
  sun.hideturtle()
  wn.bgpic("storefront.png")
percentnumb2 = 50
percentnumb = 25
def upgrade1(x,y):
  global money,dmg,price,percent,fmvmnt
  if (money < price):
    broke.write("You cant afford!", font=font_setup2)
    time.sleep(3)
    broke.clear()
  else:
money = money - round(price)
moneya.clear()
moneya.write("MONEY: $" + str(money), font=font_setup)
dmg = dmg + 5
fmvmnt = fmvmnt + 1
upg1price.clear()
percent = (percentnumb*price)/100
price = round(price) + percent
upg1price.write("$" + str(round(price)), font=font_setup)
clik = 0
mor = 0
timer = None
def clickers(x,y):
  global money,price2,percent2,clik,clkrdmg,timer,clkr_img
  if (money < price2):
    broke.write("You cant afford!", font=font_setup2)
    time.sleep(3)
    broke.clear()
  else:
    money = money - round(price2)
    moneya.clear()
    moneya.write("MONEY: $" + str(money), font=font_setup)
    clik = clik + 1
    clkrdmg = clkrdmg + 5
    csup.clear()
    percent2 = (percentnumb2*price2)/100
    price2 = round(price2) + percent2
    csup.write("$" + str(round(price2)), font=font_setup)
    while clik >= 1:
      money = money + clkrdmg
      moneya.clear()
      moneya.write("MONEY: $" + str(money), font=font_setup)
      clkr.forward(1)
      if (abs(clkr.ycor() - sun.ycor()) < 5):
        clkr.shape("rktboom.gif")
        time.sleep(1)
        clkr.hideturtle()
        clkr.shape("rocketship.gif")
        clkr.goto(0, -100)
        clkr.showturtle()
      timer = threading.Timer(1, clickers)
      timer.start
def gainpoint(x,y):
  global money,dmg,fmvmnt
  money = money + dmg
  moneya.clear()
  moneya.write("MONEY: $" + str(money), font=font_setup)
  if (abs(clkr.ycor() - sun.ycor()) < 5):
    clkr.goto(0, -100)
  clkr.forward(fmvmnt)
def backclick(x,y):
  wn.bgpic("clouds.png")
  upg1price.clear()
  csup.clear()
  broke.clear()
  back.hideturtle()
  clkr.showturtle()
  shop.showturtle()
  ugrd.hideturtle()
  sun.showturtle()
  moneya.clear()
  cs.hideturtle()
clkr.onclick(gainpoint)
cs.onclick(clickers)
shop.onclick(gostore)
back.onclick(backclick)
ugrd.onclick(upgrade1)

wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Comment: Did you mean: `timer.start()`?

Comment: @quamrana Yeah, I tried that, but even when I fixed that nothing changed, ive tried running this code by itself in a separate software without the game around it and it worked just fine